# Exponential equations, i see no other way

Tags: exponentiation, square-numbers

I have

$ 4^x - 4^\sqrt x+1 = 3*2^{x+\sqrt x}$

i have tried simplifying that equation, but that left me with a $ \sqrt x$ and an $ x$ in the exponential, which are two different values... and I am not even sure i got it right, but anyway:

$ 2^{x-2-\sqrt x} - 2^{-x} = \frac 34$

can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be an highly  transcendental function and, more than likely, numerical methods would be required.

So, consider that you are looking for the zero of function $$f(x)=4^x - 4^\sqrt x+1 - 3*2^{x+\sqrt x}$$ We know $x\geq 0$. Let try inspection
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & f(x) \\
 0 & -2. \\
 1 & -11. \\
 2 & -22.0847 \\
 3 & -25.7636 \\
 4 & 49.
\end{array}
\right)$$ So, there is a root between $3$ and $4$.

The simplest would be to use Newton method which, starting from a "reasonable" guess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Let us apply the method
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
0 & 3.50000 \\
 1 & 3.63419 \\
 2 & 3.61702 \\
 3 & 3.61669 
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for six significant figures.

Being patient and making more iterations (this would not be of any interest at all), you could arrive at $x\approx 3.616686239$.

**Edit**

After your simplication, which is good, we are let with the problem of the zero of

$$g(x)=2^{x-2-\sqrt x} - 2^{-x} - \frac 34$$ the plot of which being slightly nicer than the plot of $f(x)$ but the same problem and then same methods.